# Is there a sequence of $\{f_n\} \subset C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which converge to a function $f$ in $L^2(\mu)$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, approximation

I am trying to figure out if there is a sequence of $\{f_n\} \subset C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which converges to a function $f$ in $L^2({\mu})$, where $\mu$ is a probability measure, i.e., $\mu(dx) = \rho(x)dx$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\rho(x)$ is a density function.

I know if $\mu$ is just Lebesgue measure($dx$), there is a convergent sequence of $\{f_n\} \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which converges to a function $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but when the measure is a probability measure, it's a bit different. I'd appreciate it if you'd give me any help. Thank you.

Comment: @nicomezi Thank you for replying to me. You mean even for probability measures, not only Lebesgue measure? I know a book that shows how we can construct a sequence using mollifers for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but the same technique will apply..?

Comment: Just a side note: why you can write $\mu(dx)=\rho(x)dx$? It seems that you need to assume that $\mu$ is absolute continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Yai0Phah I just wrote it the way it was written in the book, but I think it means $\mu$ is absolute continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^{n}$ which is finite on compact sets $C_c^{\infty}( \mathbb R^{n})$ is dense in $L^{p}(\mathbb R^{n})$ for any $1\leq p<\infty$. This is proved in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: Thank you, but I was only able to find in Rudin's RCA that $C_c(X)$ is dense $L^p(X)$, where $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. (Thm 3.14). Are you referring to another theorem?

Comment: Of course Euclidean spaces are locally compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: No, I mean in Rudin's, it says $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^p(X)$, not $C_c^{\infty}(X)$ is dense in $L^p(X)$.

Comment: @withgrace1040 Then it suffices to show that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is dense in $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ under the $L^p$-topology. It should be dense even under $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$-topology, as guaranteed by convolution with mollifies.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Could you elaborate on this a little more if it is possible?

Comment: @withgrace1040 I don't know a classical reference. I just googled, and found https://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/7338/fall09/approxid.pdf, section 1.5.3 about uniform convergence.

Comment: @Yai0Phah I think I've got what you said, I mean $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ in $L^p(\mu)$ from you mentioning uniform convergence. Thank you very much!